# How to get value from a nested array by index in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am new to JS, I have been working on this case for 2 days now, experimenting how to get a value from a nested array by index.

This is my original array return from a server:

```
[
   {
      "customer":{
         "c_id":"4047",
         "quote_id":"PO3640",
         "post_date":"2021-01-25 06:26:01",
         "first_name":"Brett",
         "last_name":"H",
         "email":"brett@hafs.com.au",
         "phone":"0419778645",
         "postcode":"4128",
         "state_address":null,
         "message":"",
         "computed_price":"4102.00",
         "quote_source":"Piranha Off Road website",
         "follow_up":null,
         "follow_up_date":null
      }
   },
   {
      "vehicle":{
         "v_id":"4220",
         "make":"Toyota",
         "model":"Hilux",
         "year":"2020",
         "cab_type":"Single Cab",
         "engine":"Petrol",
         "vehicle_feature":"Reverse Camera ",
         "fitting_location":"Brisbane, QLD 4014",
         "quote_id":"PO3640"
      }
   },
   {
      "traycanops":{
         "id":"3974",
         "product":"Steel UTE Tray",
         "installation":"Piranha Branch",
         "tray_size":"2400L x 1825W x 260H",
         "tray_color":"Black",
         "tub_removal":"Please remove my tub as part of installation",
         "drivetrain":"2WD",
         "tail_lights":"Standard Globe Light",
         "claim_tub":null,
         "get_tray_floor":null,
         "canopy_size":null,
         "canopy_color":null,
         "paint_color":null,
         "paint_code":null,
         "canopy_type":null,
         "floor_type":null,
         "window_type":null,
         "deck_type":null,
         "doors":null,
         "jack_off_style":null,
         "canopy_finish":null,
         "bundle":"false",
         "powdercoat":"No",
         "powdercoat_ac":null,
         "quote_id":"PO3640",
         "base_price":"$4102.00"
      }
   },
   {
      "accessories":null
   }
]
```

Here's what I have done:

I did `var result = JSON.parse(data);` then `var customer = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0]));` and it gives me this:

[image]

I tried:

```
var customerdata = [];

$.each(customer, function(arrkey, arritem) {
  customerdata.push(customerdata[arrkey]=arritem);
});

console.log(customerdata);
```

but it gives me this:

[image]

I just want something like `customer.c_id` instead of using loop. is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `data[0].customer.c_id`?

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(` is redundant

Comment: Why have you chosen this array structure? It does not seem like a good use of an array.

Comment: Thanksss. This works `console.log(result[0].customer.c_id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/9513184/iota` and `https://stackoverflow.com/users/7941251/superstormer` , I solve this by:

```
var result = JSON.parse(data); 
console.log(result[0].customer.c_id);

//result: 4047
```